# how to change a hot key in a add-on

Tags: interface, add-on, shortcut, pie-menu

recently updated blender to "2.82a"

and figured out that the pie menu add-on changed the mode changing key to Ctrl+tab"

how can i change that key back to only "tab" not "Ctrl+tab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: user preferences]
please find this setting in edit > preferences > keymap

Comment: oh great! i will check it out